# How to make an Ingress Controller send traffic to outside IP?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

It's possible to make an Ingress Controller, or anything else (preferably something already done, not needing to code a service per say), to send traffic to an external IP?
Why: I have an application which will interact with my k8s cluster from the outside, I already know that I can use an Ingress Controller to make its connection to the cluster, but what if the other applications need to reach this external application? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the controller, but most will work with an ExternalName type Service to proxy to an arbitrary IP even if that's outside the cluster.

Comment: I'm currently using Kubernetes Ingress Controller, it's possible to route traffic to outside the cluster with this one? if not, which ones can you recommend me? thanks

Comment: That isn't a thing, do you maybe mean nginx?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant the one made by the [k8s Community](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

Comment: It does support ExtName services. See https://www.elvinefendi.com/2018/08/08/ingress-nginx-proxypass-to-external-upstream.html for an example or search around for others.